# Microsoft OData connector in SSIS gives "(401)Unauthorised" error when trying connecting to AZURE-DEVOPS Workitems

Tags: azure-devops, ssis, odata, analytics

Good day to all, I am new on the forum.

I am trying to connect SSIS to Azure Devops Workitems but it is giving the error above.
I am trying to provide a consolidated list of all Workitems over several projects in AzureDevops

I am using the standard Microsoft Odata connector in SSIS, has anyone been able to achieve this?

When I test the URL:

- https://analytics.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_odata/v2.0/WorkItems
  from Chrome or Edge I am able to see the returned data, no problem at all. My user definitely has access rights to view the analytic.

When I configure the connection manager, I put the URL above in the Service document location
and test the connection, I get:

[Error thrown by the connection manager in SSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNsZn.png)

I have tried the following as per various suggestions in the Microsoft learning, and various other
forums:

1. Using Basic authentication with my full e-mail account, and the account's password, also tested using a PAT
2. Windows authentication
3. Not sure if I should even consider using the online authentications, since the data is neither in Ax, CRM, or SharePoint.

I would be expecting the connector to be at least be successful, and then downstream provide the data requested in the columns as described by Microsoft's documentation.
There was no dialog that was indicating that authentication request was being passed to a provider.

If I view the code in the Connection manager this is what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:ConnectionManager xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:ObjectName="OData Source"
  DTS:DTSID="{1F80624B-8F04-4366-AFAC-9338C8B4621C}"
  DTS:CreationName="ODATA">
  <DTS:ObjectData>
    <ODataConnectionManager
      UserName="User@MyDomain.com"
      Url="https://analytics.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_odata/v2.0/WorkItems"
      ConnectionString="Service Document Url=https://analytics.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_odata/v2.0/WorkItems;Include Atom Elements=Auto;Include Expanded Entities=False;Integrated Security=False;User ID=User@MyDomain.com;Persist Security Info=False;Time Out=600;Schema Sample Size=25;Retry Count=5;Retry Sleep=100;Keep Alive=False;Max Received Message Size=4398046511104"
      MicrosoftOnlineServicesAuth="False"
      AuthType="BasicAuthentication"
      ConnectByProxy="False">
      <Password
        Sensitive="1">XXXXXXXXXX</Password>
    </ODataConnectionManager>
  </DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated
Best regards
Fishey